# restrict access to mp4 files from someone else's domains

Tags: video-streaming, flash, mp4, restrict

The problem is there. I have a flash player (LongTailVideo player) located at mydomain.com. 
I also have mp4 files located at x.mydomain.com, y.mydomain.com, etc. I want these files can ONLY be accessed from MYDOMAIN.COM. I dont want any other website to access my videos.

the player makes requests like this: 
http://x.mydomain.com/videos/video.mp4

Someone found out hotlinks like above and placed them into his/her own flash player and now uses my servers. How can i avoid this? Blocking referers does not work for all requests because some browsers dont send referers at all.

On each server we use apache mod_h264_streaming.
Anyone has ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i think i found a solution. it's already on the internet ))
here you go http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/discussion/4/110/458

Answer (score 0):

the real problem is that you are using http, and not rtmp; the way to secure video is to not host them over http at all, but use rtmpe and secure token in the player and on the media server. 
longtailvideo discusses this quite a bit, scaleengine implements it for their clients, you also can try to build your own jwplayer and get wowza access.